# Fetch WiFi list React native

Tags: react-native, wifi, iot, wifimanager

Is there a way to scan and get all Wifi list using React Native for both Android and iOS.
I have seen a few libraries but mostly worked for android and for iOS, no library is available that can get me the list of WiFi. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library has support for both `IOS and Android`

https://github.com/blackdeve/react-native-wifi

Or this implementation may be helpful for you if you wanted to use some 
 another library that has only support for android and you can do some implementation on the IOS side.

https://medium.com/woost/programatically-connecting-to-wifi-networks-in-react-native-on-ios-11-6103b726c3b0

Comment: I have gone through this library but i want the list of available list of WiFi and found that in iOS its not possible.

Comment: then you can add below implementation for ios.

Comment: Can you please provide me the link to implement it in iOS?

Comment: https://medium.com/woost/programatically-connecting-to-wifi-networks-in-react-native-on-ios-11-6103b726c3b0

Comment: I have gone through this link but i think it is for connecting to specific SSID and i want the list of available WiFi and then want to show it on to one of my screen.

Comment: Have a look at this
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113765